# Javascript for loop returning empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

I have a for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
  newItemsArray.push(itemsArray[i])
}
```

when I console log newItemsArray I get same as itemsArray. However if I do something like this, I get empty array with undefined values

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  newItemsArray.push(itemsArray[i])
}
```

I am trying to add certain number of items on page load so 5 items until we see 5th item then add another 5. If there is a better solution, please suggest :)

Thanks

Comment: there must be something else... I just tried and I don't get empty array in the second case

Comment: *I get empty array with undefined values* - Both are different things. either it will be an empty or filled with undefined. And if `itemsArray` will contain 5 elements then there is no issue in second code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a loop:

```
const starterItems = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "mango", "orange"]
let newItems = [...starterItems]
// if you want to add extra 5 items:
newItems = [...newItems, ...starterItems]
```

This is ES6 feature, you can read more about it here:
[Spread Operator on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Edit:
If you want to get a portion of your array, you can use filter method like so:

```
let itemsLimit = 5
newItemsArray = itemsArray.filter((item, index) => index < itemsLimit)
// later in the code you can change itemsLimit, 
// and then you need to filter the array again
itemsLimit = 10
newItemsArray = itemsArray.filter((item, index) => index < itemsLimit)
```

The code above will include every array item until itemsLimit is "reached" by items' index
This will create array you wanted. If you want to include starter position too, you can do it like this:

```
let starterPosition = 3
newItemsArray = itemsArray.filter((item, index) => index < itemsLimit && index >= starterPosition)
```

More on filter feature of Arrays in Javascript: [Filter Array method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks. It kind of gives me what I want that I can append to the newItemsArray but how can I specify which items from the itemsArray I want? For example if I have 20 items in itemsArray and I want to add first 5 items to newItemsArray then next time I want to add next 5 items then next 5 and finally last 5 items?

Comment: Okay I can now see what you meant. I will try to come up with a solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can give it a try now :)

Comment: Please consider approving my answer as the correct one, this would help me much :)

Comment: Done. I am new to stackoverflow so I was clicking the up arrow but couldnt because I am new :)